AWS ECS Otel integration fails with an error
I have a AWS ECS app container and I am trying to collect the app metrics exposed on a port by prometheus
Below is my CF template
- Name: "aws-otel-collector"
  Image: "public.ecr.aws/aws-observability/aws-otel-collector:stable"
  Command:
    - "--config=/etc/ecs/ecs-amp.yaml"
  Essential: true
  Environment:
    - Name: "AWS_PROMETHEUS_ENDPOINT"
      Value: "https://aps-workspaces.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/workspaces/ws8888/api/v1/remote_write"
    - Name: "AWS_PROMETHEUS_SCRAPING_ENDPOINT"
      Value: "http://internaldns:7300"              
  LogConfiguration:
    LogDriver: awslogs
    Options:
      awslogs-create-group: "true"
      awslogs-group: "/ecs/ecs-aws-otel-sidecar-collector"
      awslogs-region: "us-east-2"
      awslogs-stream-prefix: "ecs"
    - Image: !Ref ImageURI
      Name: !Ref ServiceName
      Essential: true
      MemoryReservation: 2048
      PortMappings:
        - ContainerPort: 7300
      LogConfiguration:
        LogDriver: awslogs
        Options:
          awslogs-create-group: "true"
          awslogs-group: "/ecs/ecs-aws-otel-sidecar-collector"
          awslogs-region: "us-east-2"
          awslogs-stream-prefix: "ecs"
      DependsOn:
        - ContainerName: "aws-otel-collector"
          Condition: "START"  

But I get error the Otel container fails to start. can someone help?
